How do I set a relative path for SQLite in workspace?
I am having a problem using a relative path with SQLx and SQLite. My workspace:
workspace/
  Cargo.toml
  .env

  base_dir/
    db.sqlite

  binary_crate/
    src/
      main.rs

The sqlx::query! macro in main.rs is marked red in Visual Studio Code. Hovering over it shows:

error returned from database: (code: 14) unable to open database file

Which also occurs when executing cargo sqlx prepare in the "binary_crate" directory:
error: error returned from database: (code: 14) unable to open database file
  --> binary_crate\src\main.rs:21:20
   |
21 |           let user = sqlx::query!(
...
28 | |         )
   | |_________^
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `sqlx::query` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

I think it's due to SQLx issue #3099. Setting DATABASE_URL in .env like this didn't change anything:
DATABASE_URL="sqlite://${CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR}/base_dir/db.sqlite"

How to workaround issue #3309 and use SQLite with a relative path on Windows 10?

What is the final value in DATABASE_URL (echo $DATABASE_URL)? I suspect you'll find that CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR did not evaluate since it is only set within a cargo build context.

You will probably need to generate the database URL dynamically, by searching for the base_dir at runtime.

@trojanfoe how will this help, given that error occurs during compile time? I want to keep compile time checking that query! is doing.
